# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to login to facebook using react-facebook-login than store the data but it's giving me an error about 'save', I don't get why, I used the exact same structure with other apps and it worked fine, could you please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Here's the models.py code:

```py
class Social(EmbeddedDocument):
    name = StringField() 
    accountId = ReferenceField(Account)
    userId = StringField()
    project = ReferenceField(Project)
    email = EmailField()
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
    add_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.add_date:
            self.add_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.add_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        return super(Social, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Facebook(Social):
    pageId = StringField(unique=True)
```

views.py

```py
class FacebookCreateView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = FacebookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.js

```py
class FacebookSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Facebook
        fields = ('name', 'accountId','userId','pageId','project','email')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        facebook_account = Facebook(
                        accountId=validated_data['accountId'],
                        name=validated_data['name'],
                        userId=validated_data['userId'],
                        pageId=validated_data['pageId'],
                        project=validated_data['project'],
                        email=validated_data['email'])
        facebook_account.save()
        return facebook_account
```

and I'm calling is from the frontend with

```
  responseFacebook = (response) => {  
  console.log(response);
  let data = new FormData(); // creates a new FormData object
    data.append('name', response.name);
    data.append('email', response.email);
    data.append('userId', response.userID);
    data.append('accountId', '5ced550e927bd2cfc01264bc');
    data.append('project', '5ce5acf4ec67314c53cae53e');
    data.append('pageId', 'tobeadded');
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/social/fb/', data)
    .then(res => { if(res.status === 200){
      console.log(res)}})
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    //window.FB.logout();
  }
```

and it's giving me this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /social/fb/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 466, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\social_accounts\views.py", line 17, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\social_accounts\serializers.py", line 18, in create
    facebook_account.save()
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\social_accounts\models.py", line 20, in save
    return super(Social, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kouter\Desktop\pfeCode\backend\env\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\document.py", line 97, in save
    self._instance.save(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Document represents a MongoDB document (i.e a record in a collection), a Document class is bound to a particular collection. An EmbeddedDocument represents a structure that gets nested in a Document.

So by design an EmbeddedDocument isn't attached to any collection unless you embed it inside a Document.

This means that you can't query or save an EmbeddedDocument class, you need to query/save the parent Document.

In your case, your instance of EmbeddedDocument is not attached to a parent Document class.

Make your Social class inherit from Document instead of EmbeddedDocument and it should be save’able.

Comment: I had the same error but the different issue. Was needed to use `EmbeddedDocumentField` when declaring fields instead of `EmbeddedDocument`. The last one is a superclass for other models, needed to embed.